# Removing Workflow Association on Content type programmatically with push to children

Tags: 2010, workflow, content-type

I am required to remove Workflow associations on a content type and from all the child content types deriving from this, as well as the list content types, deriving from the derived.
ct - A Site Content Type
wfAssoc - A workflow association with ct

```
    ct.WorkflowAssociations.Remove(wfAssoc);
    ct.UpdateWorkflowAssociationsOnChildren(false, true, true,true);
```

But the above is removing the association only with the parent, and not affecting any children or list content types. Help please? urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to delete association too and here is a code I have used:

Found [this post](http://benny56sp.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/how-to-remove-content-type-associated-workflows-and-status-fields/) and it works well for me

Hope it helps someone,

Andrew